# Delphi 10.3 error Cannot resolve unit name 'ActiveX'

Tags: delphi, activex

I'm using Delphi 10.3.3 and wrote an application about 4 months ago which used a third party Word Mailmerge unit. It said that I must include `ComObj` and `ActiveX` in `uses`, which I did. The application ran fine.

I've returned to it today to make changes and have errors, cannot resolve unit name for `ComObj` and `ActiveX`. I got around `ComObj` by changing it to `System.Win.ComObj`, which I read elsewhere on here, but cannot get around the `ActiveX` issue. Not sure why this is happening.

Have I changed something by accident?  It was working before. I'm hesitant to start re-installing libraries without understanding the issue.

Comment: `Winapi.ActiveX`?

Answer (score 2):

Probably your project has his option "Unit scope names" either empty or incomplete. That's why you have to include fully qualified unit names in the uses clause. There is no problem doing that. It is even better.

Usually the option "unit scope names" is `Winapi;System.Win;Data.Win;Datasnap.Win;Web.Win;Soap.Win;Xml.Win;Bde;System;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;Soap`

You can complete the list with whatever you need. Or leave it empty and use fully qualified unit names.

Comment: In this case, the missing one is `Winapi`.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `WinAPI.ActiveX` instead of `ActiveX` and `WinAPI.ShellAPI` instead of `ShellAPI`.